# simultaneously printing a message and capturing it

Tags: r

Let's say I have a function like the following that only shows a message.

```r
foo <- function(x) {
  if (x < 0) message("entered number is negative")
}
```

Now I want to do something depending on whether the message was shown or not. To this end, I can use `capture.output`, which will capture the message.

But the problem is that the first **message** will no longer be shown to the user:

```r
foo(-5)
#> entered number is negative

foo_new <- function(x) {
  if (x < 0) m <- capture.output(message(cat("entered number is negative")))
    
  if (length(m) > 0) return("think of a positive number")
}

foo_new(-2)
#> 
#> [1] "think of a positive number"
```

Is there alternative to `capture.output` which capture the message and also prints it simultaneously?

P.S. This is just a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: When will `message` be not shown to the user? Are you thinking `interactive()`? Or perhaps that there is an encapsulating frame that is `sink`ing (or `capture.output`ing) all output?

Comment: Why not `msg <- "message";message(msg)`? I do it like this because it allows me to compose a message in a function with `paste`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the tee-operator `%T>%` from the `magrittr` library:

```
library(magrittr)
foo_new <- function(x) {
  if (x < 0) m <- "entered number is negative" %T>% print()
  
  if (length(m) > 0) return("think of a positive number")
}

foo_new(-2)
[1] "entered number is negative"
[1] "think of a positive number"
```

Here is more information on the [tee-operator](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/tee.html) and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Given the code in the question this example is too complicated but the point it tries to make is the following:

If instead of giving a message, the message is first assigned to a variable then that variable can be returned to caller. This has the advantage of making it possible to create a message depending on the exact conditions it came to be needed.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    if(x < 0){
      msg <- paste("entered number", sQuote(xname), "is negative")
      message(msg)
      msg
    } else {
      2*x
    }
  } else {
    msg <- paste("Wrong class:", sQuote(xname), "is not numeric")
    message(msg)
    msg
  }
}

x <- 1
y <- -2
z <- "1"

foo(x)
#[1] 2

foo(y)
#entered number ‘y’ is negative
#[1] "entered number ‘y’ is negative"

foo(z)
#Wrong class: ‘z’ is not numeric
#[1] "Wrong class: ‘z’ is not numeric"
```